# Help creating a .desktop for Geometry Dash

Tags: gnome, wine, 18.04

Since the game "Geometry Dash" isn't compatible with Linux, I run it with wine.
I want to create a .desktop file for it to run it off my desktop on my Ubuntu 18.04 but things aren't going so well. When I try to run it, wine brings up an error. There is no error when I run it by double clicking the .exe file in my file manager, it works completely fine. Here is my .desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Geometry Dash
Comment=geo
Exec=wine /home/adam/Downloads/GD/GeometryDash.exe
Icon=/home/adam/Downloads/index.jpeg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=GeometryDash.exe
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: "wine brings up an error" - which error? What does it say?

Comment: The error says "The program GeometryDash.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvience. " this error doesn't pop up when I open the exe from my file manager.

Comment: The next time you start Geometry Dash from the .exe file, try dragging the icon from the launcher to the desktop.

Comment: I can already tell that is not going to work since Geometry Dash needs DLLS in the same folder the exe is in in order to work.

Comment: I can run wine applications from desktop files without issue, so this may be specific to that executable. What is the output of `wine /home/adam/Downloads/GD/GeometryDash.exe`? Does `GeometryDash.exe` depend on the current working directory or read an environment variable?